# Change Search box text only for Mysite in SharePoint2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search

We configured Mysite,having a search at right side,having text like search as shown in image,i want to change the text only for mysites as "Search People".Can any one help on this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the below jquery:

```
$(".ms-InlineSearch-Outline-Baseline input").val("Search People");
```